# Please help me understand あなたがそれを考え直して止めてもらえればと思います。

Tags: translation

This sentence seems to me to be a bit convoluted and I am not quite sure what it means. If anyone can help me break it up, I would really appreciate it.

あなたがそれを考え直して止めてもらえればと思います。

As you can see, there are multiple constructions used within this sentence (1) Vte 止める, (2) Vte もらう, (3) (4) Potential form + provisional form (もらえれば) and (5) と思う

As I understand it, (1) is "stop and V" in a sense, and I think I can understand that part, but the combination of (2),(3),(4) and (5) which results in ～てもらえればと思います makes my head turn a bit. あなたが Vte もらう is, I believe, (s.o.) Vte for you, (3) is "can", (4) is "if", (5) is "I think", so if I combine the whole thing, I believe I'll get

"I think if (they) can reconsider for you..."

Am I correct here? If not, can you help me go through this sentence? Thank you for any help in advance.

Answer (score 3):

To break it down,

- それを考え直して止める
  to reconsider and stop it
- それを考え直して止めてもらう
  to reconsider and stop it **(for me)**
- それを考え直して止めてもらえれば。
  (I would appreciate) **if** you could reconsider and stop it for me.
- 「それを考え直して止めてもらえれば」と思う
  I think "I would appreciate if you could reconsider and stop it for me"

Or more naturally, the whole sentence means "I would appreciate if you reconsider and stop it."

Conditional れば can be used like this (without the subsequent part) to euphemistically express your request or hope.

> - 明日来て頂ければと思います。 Would you mind coming tomorrow?
> - もっとお金があれば！ If only I had more money!

Comment: Thank you for your help. However, in Vte もらう construction, isn't the subject (marked by が) the recipient of the favor, and the giver is marked by に instead (page 57 Genki 2, page 262 A Dictionary of Basic Japanese grammar)?

Comment: Also isn't the conditional/provisional form of もらう is もらえば instead of もらえれば, which I believe to be the conditional form of the potential form もらえる of もらう. Does that change anything here?

Comment: @ProjectBook Ah, you're right, もらえれば has a potential meaning, although the change in meaning is minimal ("if you reconsider" becomes "if you could reconsider"). Regarding "recipient of favor", please give me some time.

Comment: @ProjectBook Hmm, I think we need to add a small mental comma between あなたがそれを考え直して and 止めてもらえれば. As you pointed out, あなた**が**止めてもらえればと思います sounds awkward to me, and you have to say (私は)あなた**に**止めてもらえればと思います instead. But the original sentence sounds just fine because of the te-form.

Comment: So you mean we should read it as 「あなたがそれを考え直して、止めてもらえればと思います。」It still seems a bit strange to me. Could it be that the sentence is malformed to begin with? Do you think this sentence sound natural to a native speaker, or is it just a contrived example that some non-native speaker came up with?

Comment: It would be 「『あなたがそれを考え直して、止めてもらえれば』と思います」. As a native speaker myself, I'm not very good at grammar, but  I believe this sentence is totally natural, and that's why I initially didn't understand why you thought this usage of もらう seemed strange to you.

Comment: Wait why is it in 『...』? Does that means it's a direct quote [ "..." I think ] ? Does the sentence still mean "I would appreciate if you reconsider and stop it" when it's in the form 「『あなたがそれを考え直して、止めてもらえれば』と思います」? Thank you for being patient with me.

Comment: @ProjectBook The symbols are [alternate quotation marks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_punctuation#Quotation_marks) in Japanese, as much as writing "I think: 'I would appreciate if you reconsider and stop it'". Do you mean you're not familiar with Japanese quote grammar?