# sentence structure and extent of quotion in this statement

Tags: particle-に, particle-で, quotes

> speaker「だから、お前が俺のことをよく見てくれてるって思ったらなんかちょっと嬉しくてさ」
>
> girl  「……べ、別にあんたのことそんな風に見た覚えはないけど、そう見えたのよ」
>
> speaker「ってとは、自分でも気付かぬうちに俺のことをよく見ていたってことになるな」
>
> girl 「ば、ばっかじゃないの！？　なんでそうなるのよ！？」
>
> speaker 「**俺としては出来ればそんな感じに見てくれてたらって思うけどな。その方が嬉しいし**」

-

> that why, after thinking about the fact that you really understand me, i'm kinda glad
>
> it's not like i see you in *that* way, that's just how you look.
>
> that means, before you realized it yourself, you you've really come to
>   understand me
>
> are you dumb? How the hell did you come to that conclusion?
>
> **For me personally,if possible, thinking  " if you looking at me with that sort of feeling" ....,  that makes me happy**

how much does the the 思う quote emcompass?

[俺としては...見てくれてたら]? [出来ればそんな感じに見てくれてたら]? [そんな感じに見てくれてたら]?

When would you use に over で for the  原因/理由/means/agent purpose like with 感じに見る？

is there a better way to interpret the ...たら in this quote?

Thank you.

Comment: My translation of dialog (different than yours): A) I'm saying, I'm kinda happy you're looking at me so much B) what, I don't really remember looking at you that you. It just seemed that way (to you). A) That means, you've been looking at me without realizing what you're doing. Just so you know! B) That's non-sense! Why would it be that way? A) For me, if possible, I'd rather think you've been looking at me that way. That makes me happy.

Comment: with the prior context only the [注意力を働かせて観察するさま](https://thesaurus.weblio.jp/content/%E3%82%88%E3%81%8F%E8%A6%8B%E3%82%8B) definition would apply. Speaker asked girl to describe him, and she gives some answers  that he feels that only someone close to him would give.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the quoted part:

> 俺としては「出来ればそんな感じに見てくれてたら」って思うけどな。
>   For me personally, I think "if possible, if you are seeing me like that, (that's good)".

Sentence-end たら can be used to express suggestion and hope. In the latter case, you can think something like いい, ありがたい or 嬉しい is omitted after たら.

そんな感じに and そんな感じで are interchangeable in this context. It means "like that" or "in such a way."

Comment: would the "その方が嬉しいし" afterwards be related to ...たら inside the quote ? Or is その方 referring to the this way of thinking as a whole?

Comment: @charu Yes その方 refers to そんな感じに見る. He wants her to look at him rather than ignoring him.

Comment: "俺としては「出来ればそんな感じに見てくれてたらその方が嬉しいし」って思うけどな。" would be the more accurate way to look at it?

Comment: @charu You should not try to join the two sentences like that.. The second sentence is indeed a part of this thoughts, but it's not inside the quote, at least grammatically. Ending a sentence with たら (or hypothetical form in general) is not uncommon at all. For instance, see: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/56782/5010

Comment: my natural way of reading その方が嬉しいし is interpreting その方 as  [「出来ればそんな感じに見てくれてたら」って思う], in other words  "this way of thinking make me happy".  But the reply of "その方 refers to そんな感じに見る. He wants her to look at him rather than ignoring him", refers to the contents inside the quote

Comment: @charu その方 is comparing two possible attitudes of her toward the speaker (i.e., "she is interested and looks at me" vs "uninterested"), not two ways of thinking of the speaker ("thinking she's interested" vs "not thinking she's interested").