# Value-augmenting なれば

Tags: translation, ambiguity

The following quote is from [this](https://www.asahi.com/and_travel/articles/SDI2019021202191.html?iref=comtop_fbox_u04) article.

> 神苑にこれほどの梅が植えられたのも、そんなふうに訪れる人々の憩いに**なれば**という思いから。

I wonder what になれば means here. What value does it bring over having simply になる?

Comment: Related? https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/56783/9831

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think using なれば rather than なる in your example shows that there is **a wish or hope** that planting such plum trees will contribute to the relaxation of the visitors.

English has a similar way of using a conditional expression to express a wish or hope. For example...

- "**If** you ***wouldn't*** mind taking that poster off the wall."
- "Yeah, **if** you ***could*** just get me some cereal at the store."
- "**If** I ***could*** just have a moment of your time, sir."

In Japanese an expression with ~ば + と思{おも}う is common. For example...

- ご利用{りよう}にな**れば**と思います。  (I hope you will use it)
- ご記入{きにゅう}いただ**ければ**と思います。  (If you could just fill this in for me)
- 次週{じしゅう}ご来場{らいじょう}いただ**ければ**と思います。  (If we could have you could come to our location next week)

The meaning of these examples can change significantly if you remove the ~ば construction.

- ご利用になると思います。  (I think you will use it)
- ご記入いただくと思います。  (I think he will fill it in for us)
- 次週ご来場いただくと思います。  (I think they will be coming to our location next week)